# How to use the Max Value from a Collection in a C# Where Clause?

Tags: c#, lambda, collections, max, .net-4.8

I have a collection of activity phases. I want to get only one activity phase. That activity phase needs to be the one with the highest workflow step value. I tried the following, but no luck:

```
ActivityPhases = a.ApplicationActivityPhas
                 .Where(w => w.ActivityPhas.WorkFlowStep == Max(w.ActivityPhas.WorkFlowStep))
                 .(Select(p => p.ActivityPhas.ActivityPhase)
```

> "Max" does not exist in the current context.

Comment: "but no luck" - Does it not compile, does it give the wrong answer, does it throw an exception?   Please be specific/

Comment: Order by then take 1

Comment: For the code that I posted in the question, it says that "Max" does not exist in the current context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, get the max value, then get the object that have the max value.

```
var maxValue = a.ApplicationActivityPhas.Max(w => w.ActivityPhas.WorkFlowStep);
var activityPhases = a.ApplicationActivityPhas.Where(w => w.ActivityPhas.WorkFlowStep == maxValue);
```

If you have only one activity with the max value, you can use First instead.

```
var activityPhase = a.ApplicationActivityPhas.First(w => w.ActivityPhas.WorkFlowStep == maxValue);
```

Comment: Of course none should add a new record with higher max value between the first and the second line.

Answer (score 1):

Is using `.Where()` a requirement? The title states it, but according to the question phrasing, it does not look like it is. If this answer is inappropriate due to it being a requirement, please let me know, and I will remove it.

##### .NET Framework 4.8

You could order your activity phases by their respective `ActivityPhas.WorkFlowStep` value in descending order, and then select the first activity phase:

```csharp
var activityPhase = a.ApplicationActivityPhas
    .OrderByDescending(aap => aap.ActivityPhas.WorkFlowStep)
    .First();
```

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5RBJAj).

##### .NET 6

I think you could achieve what you want by using the [`.MaxBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.maxby?view=net-6.0) operator. It lets you define e.g. which property to use as the comparison value for each object, and returns the first object with the maximum value for that specific property.

```csharp
var activityPhase = a.ApplicationActivityPhas
    .MaxBy(aap => aap.ActivityPhas.WorkFlowStep);
```

Example fiddle (using a random class) [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mcekMW).

Comment: I received an error that ICollection ApplicationActivityPhas does not contain a definition for MaxBy.

Comment: @LupeH I have added a comment about the availability of `.MaxBy()`. I didn't think about that, seeing as no version was specified in the question or tags.